# How to modify a controller variable?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

There is a variable sent by a controller :

```
    public function ajout()
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['_mode'] = MODE_AJOUT;
        $this->load->view('mission/mission', $data);
    }
```

In the view I want to change the variable `$_mode` to have a value `MODE_MODIF` ( a constant from the `constants.php` config file ) after submitting a form by `ajax`:

```
$("#form_sample_1").on("submit", function(){
    var url_ = "<?php echo ( $_mode == MODE_AJOUT ? site_url('ajax/ajouterMission') : site_url('ajax/modifierMission') ); ?>";
    $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            url:  url_,
            async: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                        alert("Donn\351es enregistr\351es !");
                     }
     });
    return false;
});
```

How to do that ? or is that impossible ?

Comment: show ajex code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add atribute .

```
         MY_Class Extends CI_Controller{
           private $_mode; 
         }

         public function ajout(){
          $data = array();
          $data['_mode'] = MODE_AJOUT;
          $this->load->view('mission/mission', $data);
        }

         //Call this function with ajax
        public checkForm(){
         $this->_mode = $newValue; //set attribute
         $data['_mode'] = $this->_mode; //get attribute
         echo json_encode($data);
       }
```